# How to set default close operation in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

When I press the red close button, I want the window not to close on JavaFX.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Javadocs for `Window.setOnCloseRequest()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty):

> Called when there is an external request to close this Window. The installed event handler can prevent window closing by consuming the received event.

So all you need is

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(Event::consume);
```

or, if you are going to perform other actions as well:

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    // do some stuff...
    event.consume();
});
```